# Permission denied for user having a secondary group in an NFS shared folder

Tags: debian, nfs, nfs4

I have a NFS shared folder (storage) that can be accessed by other machines on my network. The right user can read and write files and folder in that storage, but I've created another user and affected the same group as the original user as a secondary group, but when I try to access the data, I get a permission denied.

Here's the full detail:

## On the storage server side (Debian 10):

```
$> cat /etc/exports
/storage 10.0.0.0/16(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)


$> id original_user  # I replaced the real user by "original_user" but the rest (IDs) is the same
uid=1010(original_user) gid=1010(original_user) groups=1010(original_user)
```

(second user is not on the storage server)

## On the client server (Debian 10):

```
$> cat /etc/auto.storage
storage    -fstype=nfs,rw    storage:/storage

$> cat /etc/auto.master
+auto.master
/var/nfs /etc/auto.storage --ghost

$> id original_user
uid=1010(original_user) gid=1010(original_user) groups=1010(original_user)

$> id second_user
uid=1001(second_user) gid=1001(second_user) groups=1001(second_user),1010(original_user)
```

As you can see, `second_user` is on the correct group.

Now, the folder permissions :

```
$> ls -l /var/nfs/storage/
drwxr-x--- 3 original_user original_user  4096 Jun 23 15:43 data
```

(Group is read and execute, so everyone in the group `original_user` should have access to the content of `data`).

But when I try the following with `second_users` :

```
$second_user> ls -l /var/nfs/storage/data/
-bash: cd: /var/nfs/storage/data/: Permission denied
```

Why is that?

I discovered that Debian adds a --manage-gids on the RPC at /etc/default/nfs-kernel-server:

```
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids"
```

I tried commenting it and restart the server, this lead to the nfs storage stopping being available (trying to list `/var/nfs/storage` on the client hang forever).

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the permission of */var/nfs/storage/data* directory?

Comment: `drwxr-x--- 3 original_user original_user`, I've shared it. Are you interested in something else?

Comment: you shouldn't comment it out. Just replace with an empty one: **RPCMOUNTDOPTS=""**

Comment: Sorry for that late response here. Tried it, but it didn't work unfortunately :/